# System of PDEs involving two distinct functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given functions $f, g: \mathbf{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$, how would one go about solving the system

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= -g(x, y)\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} &= f(x, y)
\end{align*}

for $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear differential operator $D = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Then your equations read $Df = -g, Dg = f$, and so $D^2f = D(Df) = D(-g) = -Dg = -f$, i.e. $(D^2 + 1)f = 0$. Now this looks a bit simpler since we just need to find a function $f$ that is in the kernel of the differential operator $D^2 + 1$, and then $g$ is simply $-Df$. There might be several ways to find such an $f$ but my first thought would be that this be much easier to solve this if $D$ only involved one partial instead of two. Luckily if we make the change of coordinates $x=u, y = u-v$, then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = D$$
and so we can now solve the equation $f_{uu} = -f$. This is very similar to the ODE $y'' = -y$, which is well known to have the solutions $y = A\cos t + B\sin t$ for arbitrary constants $A,B$; therefore we can see that $f(u,v) = p(v)\cos u + q(v)\sin u$ for arbitrary functions $p,v$, and
$$ g(u,v) = -Df(u,v) = -f_u(u,v) = -p(v)\sin u + q(v)\cos u. $$
Converting back to $x,y$ coordinates with $u = x, v = x-y$ yields
$$ f(x,y) = p\left(x-y\right)\cos x + q\left(x-y\right)\sin x, $$
$$ g(x,y) = q\left(x-y\right)\cos x - p\left(x-y\right)\sin x $$
for arbitrary functions $p, q$, which I will leave to you to verify solves the original system of PDEs.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thanks for your response. Please give me a few days to think about this before I accept.

Comment: No problem, I am happy to provide further detail/explanation if you need.

Comment: I'll also add, to gain clarity I would suggest trying to see how the ordinary differential system $y'(t) = x(t), x'(t) = -y(t)$ leads to the linear ODE $y''(t) = -y(t)$, solve it, then compare this to the method I gave in my answer.